# Returning functions for events

Tags: flutter, functional-programming

I want to call a function that would return another function to be used as onChange event handler for a Textfield input.

I am trying the code below, but for some reason the emulator building process just stuck, no error showed and emulation not working.

```
Function testing(Counter counter) {
  var somefunction = (String s) { 
    counter.increment();
  };
  return somefunction;
}


//widget class
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);
    return TextField(
      onChanged: testing(counter),
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: _placeholder),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't see a real reason for returning a function in that scenario. Dart does not support FP by default, instead you should stick to OO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of function returning another function as result

```dart
bool Function(String) testing(Counter counter) {
  var somefunction = (String s) { 
    counter.increment();
  };
  return somefunction;
}
```

also this statement could be simplified to

```dart
bool Function(String) testing(Counter counter) => (String s) { 
  counter.increment();
};
```

For readability you can define a [typedef](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs). Probably most used one is:

```dart
typedef WidgetBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context);
```

So original example code may be converted to something like

```dart
typedef StringTester = bool Function(String);
StringTester testing(Counter counter) => (String s) {
  counter.increment();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This example should show how to use functions in events like onChange:

```
class TextLengthExample extends StatelessWidget {

  testing(string) {
    return print(string.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      // Remember "(str) =>" before the method otherwise it does not run properly.
      onChanged: (str) => testing(str), 
      // Alternative syntax:    
      //onChanged: (str) { 
      //  testing(str)
      //},
      // Oneliner:
      //onChanged: (str) => print(str.length), 
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Test"),
    );
  }
}
```